# SendGrid for non-production environments

Tags: sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid for sending emails. Some of these emails are sent to users of the system. In non-production environments, we have configuration values to send to alternate email addresses instead of actual email addresses.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid this and have it work the same way in prod and non-prod. Based on research, SendGrid has a sandbox mode which looked promising, but I still need a way to actually look at the email generated by SendGrid for testing purposes.

Does anyone know if there's a way to view sandbox emails, or to configure the SendGrid account itself to redirect emails? I'm using a separate SendGrid account for prod and non-prod, so if it's an account-level configuration I can set, that would work.

Comment: I also want to view emails sent to the sandbox so I can check they are correct without sending actual emails.